# How to set an attribute like this example with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, setattribute, createelement

Noob question,

I've been trying to implement the [simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) library which seems pretty easy to work with. you just need to construct the div in the below format. But for some reason I need to make the div dynamically using javascript:

```
<div data-simplebar></div>
```

This is what I tried, but doesn't seem to work:

```
var scrollBox=document.createElement('div');
scrollBox.setAttribute("data-simplebar","")
```

I also thought about doing this, which didn't work either:

```
var scrollBox=document.createElement('div data-simplebar');
```

Comment: The first block of code you have there looks like it should work, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you adding it to the dom? : https://jsfiddle.net/coktvoag/

Comment: That code [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/kwmj2dy1/) assuming you do append it to the page at some point. (`createElement` just creates it, it doesn't put it in the DOM tree.) More likely, the issue is that the library is looking for these elements before you add that one, and you need to tell it about the new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the div you made to the dom at some point, something like `document.body.appendChild(scrollBox);`